# C# Backgroundworker data invalid - thread issue?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, backgroundworker

please take a look at my issue:

I have logic developed that will run over a long period of time. While running the logic, I want to report the status to a progress bar. Great! So i used background worker:

```
_backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
_backgroundWorker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundWorker_DoWork);
_backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += new  ProgressChangedEventHandler(backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged);
_backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
_backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

within backgroundWorker_Dowork, I have the logic that does the job. I also declare a timer that gets invoked every 50ms to report status.(within backgroundWorker_DoWork):

```
timer.Elapsed += (senderr, ee) => timer_Elapsed();
_timer.Interval = 50;
```

within timer_Elapsed, I update the UI control by calling _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(0); The reason I dont call ReportProgress within backgroundWorker_DoWork is because although my code takes a while, the while loop I used to do my work is extremely fast. If I call ReportProgres at the end of my while loop, then the same non-responsive type of UI problem occurs.

Now my issue is when processing little data, when timer_Elapsed is called, all the variables and data are 0 and null. and I cant seem to figure out why.. I have extensive experience with multi threaded programming but C# masks everything and I have no clue which thread has what data...

the timer is then diposed within the backgroundWorker_DoWork after the long running logic is completed.

any idea on why those data are invalid? any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: Anything called from DoWork (including event fires) are handled on the thread running the BackgroundWorker.  Can you post your code for timer_Elapsed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show all your code, but my understanding of your description is that `timer.Elapsed` runs on a different thread than your background worker, hence you have a race condition.

Also, your remark about "when processing little data" makes me think that your `timer.Elapsed` is called after the background worker has already completed and you're not handling this case correctly.

I would suggest that you report progress directly from the background worker. Just don't do it *every* iteration of your loop, just one out of 1000 (actual number should get chosen according to how fast your loop spins).

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the while loop, but not on every iteration. Two options:

1. Only report progress on every n<sup>th</sup> iteration (say every 100<sup>th</sup> iteration)
2. Maintain a timestamp, when when 50ms has elapsed, report status and update timestamp